# thunderbird: different color for new email, when I am only a "cc" recipient, instead of regular "to" recipient

Tags: email, thunderbird

Is there a way to use different color for new email in inbox, when I am only a "cc/bcc" recipient, instead of regular "to" recipient ?

I am alredy using custom color for new emails in inbox. This is what i have in my `userChrome.css`:

```
/* unread messages */
#threadTree treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(unread),
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(hasUnreadMessages-true) {
    font-weight: bold !important;
    color: red !important;
}
```

How can I modify it, so that new emails are colored differently, depending wether I am in "to" or "cc/bcc" ?

Comment: Looking thru the [Gecko Chrome-only CSS reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Chrome/CSS) and [Mozilla CSS Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Chrome/CSS), there doesn't seem to be a CSS-related way to access the To/Cc/Bcc state.

Comment: As a side note, you might be better served to post future Thunderbird-related questions over on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). There are currently 133 users watching the thunderbird tag over there, while there are only 7 here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it seems they can't be set using CSS, colors *can* be set based on To, Cc, and Bcc state by setting up one or more message filters to tag the messages.

First, create a tag of the desired color, e.g. a tag named `Cc/Bcc`. Then, create a filter to tag messages at a particular email address received as either Cc or Bcc to `Cc/Bcc`, as shown below. Use your own email address, of course.

By default, there is no `Bcc` in the list of headers to match. A custom `Bcc` header entry needs to be added to the list of headers when setting up the rules. To do so:

1. Select `Customize...` from the drop-down list for selecting the header to match,
2. type `Bcc` in the "Customize Headers" dialog that appears,
3. click `Add`,
4. click `OK`.

One caveat: The functionality for removing a custom header seems not to work (at least in the 64-bit version of Thunderbird 68.8.0), so add carefully.

[image: Screenshot of Filter Rules dialog]